# How to modify a view in my storyboard to support scrolling in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am in the middle of making an iPhone app. I have a storyboard with several views. One of these views has a lot of content that fills the whole iPhone 5 screen with no room to spare. I want to make this screen scroll for older iPhone 3.5" screens. Does anyone know of a simple way to do this? I tried just changing the UIView class to UIScrollView, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
Let your view be 'contentView'

Add this code to viewDidLoad in .m file.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[scrollView addSubview:contentView];
scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

OR

Just drag and drop a UIScrollView in your xib file and put your view inside that scrollview. Then in code *viewDidAppear* just set the contentSize of scrollview.

```
scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size;
```

If you need scrollview fill whole screen set the frame of scrollview just before setting contentSize

```
scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Edit : Just drag and drop a UIScrollView to your ViewController and arrange like this.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the simplistic question, but where do I put this code?

Comment: its better do second option. In xib just put a scrollview and make your content view inside that scrollview. In viewDidAppear just set the contentsize.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. How do i "put my view inside my scrollview"?

Comment: I would like to use the first method, but am not sure which parts go in my .h or .m files, or where.

Comment: Did you connected your contentView to an IBOutlet ?

Comment: I did connect my UIView to an IBOutlet in my .m file between my `@Interface` and `@end`, but I suspect this is the wrong place. I appreciate all your help, I'm normally more functional than this!

Comment: make that IBOutlet in your .h file and connect it.

Answer (score 2):

Put all your content in your scrollView from the beginning 
and put below code in your viewDidLoad

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480) {

     self.scrollViewMain.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set scrollview content size for enabling scrolling of your scrollview.

you can set it directly from scrollview property from XIB or do it programatically.